# C- text files write details

Tags: c, file

I tried to do something simple to write some detail that I got from user to a txt file and it works but I want them to be at the same line and for some reason the last one that I write is in the next line.

```
printf("\nPassengers Details:\n===================\n");

printf("Please Enter Passenger`s Passport-->:");
scanf("%d", &p1.passportnum);
getchar();
printf("\nPlease Enter Passenger`s First NAME-->:");
fgets(p1.firstname, SIZE, stdin);
printf("\nPlease Enter Passenger`s Last NAME-->:");
fgets(p1.lastname, SIZE, stdin);

fpassengers = fopen("passengers.txt", "w");
fprintf(fpassengers,"%d %s %s", p1.passportnum, p1.firstname, p1.lastname);

fclose(fpassengers);
```

In the file it writes the first 2 at the same line and the `last name` in the next line .

How do I make them be at same line??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New line while writing to file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097532/new-line-while-writing-to-file-in-c)

Comment: `fgets` stores the newline in the buffer, so that's why.

Comment: and how do i change it? i tried to use `scanf` insted but same same

Comment: @Badda totally opposite problem - this is closer I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input

Comment: You can use fseek() to go back a line.

Comment: i changed both of `fgets` to `scanf` and works thanks! btw any wany of canceling the option of `fgets` to get the newline to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)

Comment: How to remove the newline: `p1.lastname[strlen(p1.lastname)] = '\0';`

Comment: @CareyGregory not quite....

Comment: @MichaelWalz Other than error checking, which I leave to the OP to add, what's not quite about it?

Comment: @CareyGregory `p1.lastname[strlen(p1.lastname)] = '\0'` -> `p1.lastname[strlen(p1.lastname) - 1] = '\0'`

Comment: @420Friendlly: Take the habit of *ending* `printf` control string with `\n` (or use `fflush` wisely). Compile with all warnings & debug info e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and **use the debugger** `gdb`

Comment: @MichaelWalz lol, duh. More coffee before coding comments.

Answer (score 1):

You have just to replace `\n` with `\0`in the last position of `p1.firstname` and `p1.lastname`. Here is a generic example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 128

int main() {
    FILE* fpassengers;
    int passport_num;
    char first_name[SIZE];
    char last_name[SIZE];

    printf("\nPassengers Details:\n===================\n");
    printf("Please Enter Passenger`s Passport-->:");

    scanf("%d", &passport_num);
    getchar();

    printf("\nPlease Enter Passenger`s First NAME-->:");
    fgets(first_name, SIZE, stdin);
    first_name[strlen(first_name)-1] = '\0';

    printf("\nPlease Enter Passenger`s Last NAME-->:");
    fgets(last_name, SIZE, stdin);
    last_name[strlen(last_name)-1] = '\0';

    fpassengers = fopen("passengers.txt", "w");
    if (fpassengers == NULL) {
        perror("Fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fprintf(fpassengers,"%d %s %s", passport_num, first_name, last_name);

    fclose(fpassengers);
}
```

You have also to check the return value of fopen.

Comment: You need to change: `last_name[strlen(first_name)-1] = '\0';` --> `last_name[strlen(last_name)-1] = '\0';`. That said, there are [better ways to remove the newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input). Note that the method you use has UB if the input string is empty or if there is an error in `fgets()`. Also, better and less error-prone to use `fgets()` and `sscanf()`  instead of combining `scanf()`, `getchar()` and `fgets()`.

Comment: And, `int main()` is an implementation-dependent signature; should be `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`